Why does an HTML file display properly in Firefox after selecting "Show Preview" but uses Chrome instead after selecting "Open in Browser"?
In VS Code, an HTML file is displayed in a Firefox browser as desired when Show Preview is selected. When the hamburger menu is selected for More Browser Action, the options shown are:

Open in Browser
Find in Page
Open Devtools Pane

and I used to get a full page displayed in Firefox.
However, for some reason, I now get the page displayed in Chrome. Can't find a reason for it — all "browser" settings have been set to Firefox.
How do I get everything to displayed in the Firefox browser as desired?
launch.json file:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
        "name": "Launch Firefox",
        "type": "firefox",
        "request": "launch",
        "reAttach": true,
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
       }
     ]
 }

settings.json file:
{
    "livePreview.customExternalBrowser": "Firefox",
    "workbench.externalBrowser": "firefox"
}

